# Xamarin Android : Retain data on activity change and come back

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm developing an app in Xamarin.android where in I want to retain the data of Edit Text, spinners etc. whenever i revisit to that activity. E.g.

Activity A contains Edit Text, Spinners.

I navigate to Activity B from Activity A, and whenever I come back to Activity A from B I want to retain those values of Edit Text and Spinners.

I tried using Put Extra and Get Extra, but as there are multiple values this approach seems to be wrong.

```
 var activity2 = new Intent (this, typeof(Activity2));
   activity2.PutExtra ("MyData", "Data from Activity1");
   StartActivity (activity2);
```

Also OnSaveInstanceState and OnRestoreInstanceState is not working out for me as I'm using Fragments in my Activity A

Please Guide

Answer (score 0):

Can't your fragments save their own data using [Fragment.onSaveInstanceState](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)) ?

Answer (score 0):

in your case you need to save this temp data in [Shared Preference](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/4758/android-shared-preference)

here is example

```
ISharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences(this); 
ISharedPreferencesEditor editor = prefs.Edit();
editor.PutInt(("number_of_times_accessed", accessCount++);
editor.PutString("date_last_accessed", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MMM-dd"));
editor.Apply();
```

save what ever you want int or string

and when you load you activity retrieve this data and set it to your views

```
ISharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences(this); 
string passedString = prefs.GetString(key, defValue); 
// here set retured data to your view
// Ex : YourEditText.Text = passedString
```

hope this help